# What do I need to change to make Scala 2.13 MultiDict work as a drop-in replacement for 2.12's MultiMap?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

For Scala code < 2.13, I am using a MultiMap as defined here [MultiMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MultiMap.html).  Using the example code found there, I was hoping to update it by simply replacing the code:

```
val mm = new HashMap[Int, Set[String]] with MultiMap[Int, String]
```

with

```
val mm2 = new HashMap[Int, Set[String]] with MultiDict[Int, String]
```

But instead I get the following error:

```
illegal inheritance; 
<$anon: Int => scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] 
with scala.collection.MultiDict[Int,String]> inherits different type instances of trait Iterable:
Iterable[(Int, String)] and Iterable[(Int, scala.collection.mutable.Set[String])]
```

Answer (score 3):

What you'll want to do is:

1. Instantiate a mutable `MultiDict[K, V]`.
2. Add and remove items from that collection as needed via the methods inherited from the `Growable[(K, V)]` and `Shrinkable[(K, V)]` traits.
3. Use the [`sets`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-collection-contrib_2.13/0.2.2/scala/collection/mutable/MultiDict.html#sets:scala.collection.Map%5BK,scala.collection.Set%5BV%5D%5D) method on the instance when you need to access the collection as a `Map[K, Set[V]]`.

In the following example, both `md1` and `md2` are mutable `MultiDict[Int, String]` objects that are equivalent at the end of the code block:

```
locally {
  import scala.collection.mutable

  val md1 = mutable.MultiDict.empty[Int, String]
  md1.addOne(1 -> "one")
  md1.addOne(1 -> "uno")
  md1.addOne(2 -> "two")
  md1.addOne(2 -> "dos")

  val md2 = mutable.MultiDict.from[Int, String](
    Seq(1 -> "one", 1 -> "uno", 2 -> "two", 2 -> "dos")
  )
}
```

Comment: Note that `MultiDict` is from https://github.com/scala/scala-collection-contrib and not available in the standard lib, afaict. (Hoping to save folks from the time it took me to figure out :) ).